# Google Talk drop down style on Honeycomb

Tags: android, textview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying to get a Google Talk-like effect in our app. It's not letting me upload an image right now (either from web or locally), but here is a link to an example.

http://www.eweek.com/images/stories/slideshows/014211_honeycomb_xoom/honeycomb13.jpg

The "Available" text has an arrow on the far right. It looks like a stylized TextView, but I'm not sure. Is there a built in style that has this arrow? I can't find something similar in the documentation, so I'm starting to think it is something custom they did for the Google Talk app. Does anyone know if there is an existing style for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) looks like this on Honeycomb.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't seeing it as the spinner before because of a custom style we had.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a modified list view, as those things give you loads of customization and the behavior seems consistent.